# Estou com um erro que não sei identificar no println

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Essas são minhas classes porem mesmo assim ocorre o erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at funcionario20.Principal.main(Principal.java:16)
>   /home/lucas/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
>   Segue meu código:

```
Classe Principal:

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Funcionario lucas = new Funcionario();
        lucas.setSalario(1856.85);
        lucas.setEndereco("Rua Frei Caneca");
        lucas.setEstadoCivil("Solteiro");
        lucas.setNomeDoDepartamento("Auxiliar");

        lucas.pessoa = new Pessoa();
        lucas.pessoa.setNome("Lucas Alves Cardoso de Jesus");
        lucas.pessoa.setRg(123456891);

        lucas.data.setDatadia(13);
        lucas.data.setDatames(05);
        lucas.data.setDiaano(94);

        lucas.getAnual();

        System.out.println(lucas.getEndereco());

    }

}
```

Classe Funcionario

```
public class Funcionario {

    private String NomeDoDepartamento;
    private double Salario;
    private double anual;
    private String EstadoCivil;
    private String Endereco;
    int proximo = 0;
    Pessoa pessoa;
    Data data;


    //get obter set mudar

    public String getNomeDoDepartamento(){
        return this.NomeDoDepartamento;
    }

    public void setNomeDoDepartamento(String nomedepartamento){
        this.NomeDoDepartamento = nomedepartamento;
    }

    public double getSalario(){
        return this.Salario;
    }

    public void setSalario (double salario){
        this.Salario = salario;
    }

    public double getAnual(){
        return this.Salario*12;
    }

    public String getEstadoCivil(){
        return this.EstadoCivil;
    }

    public void setEstadoCivil(String estadocivil){
        this.EstadoCivil = estadocivil;
    }

    public String getEndereco(){
        return this.Endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco (String endereco){
        this.Endereco = endereco;
    }


}
```

Comment: Seu Problema não esta no println! sua classe `funcionário` contem alguns erro. vc não definiu um setDatadia(), setDatames(), setDiaAno(). na classe principal você esqueceu de definir propriedades a `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não definiu a propriedade `data` antes da linha 16 da sua classe principal:

```
lucas.data = new Data();
lucas.data.setDatadia(13);
```

Fora isso tenho pelo menos 2 dicas pra te dar:

1) Use o construtor para setar novos objetos ou crie construtores auxiliares:

```
public Funcionario() {
  this.pessoa = new Pessoa();
  this.data = new Data();
}
```

OU

```
public Funcionario(){} // construtor padrão

public Funcionario(Pessoa pessoa) {
  this.pessoa = pessoa;
}
public Funcionario(Data data) {
  this.data = data;
}
public Funcionario(Pessoa pessoa, Data data) {
  this.pessoa = pessoa;
  this.data = data;
}
```

Assim permitindo:

```
Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario(); 
// funcionário padrão, sem Pessoa e Data

Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario(new Pessoa()); 
// funcionário com Pessoa e sem Data

Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario(new Data()); 
// funcionário sem Pessoa e com Data

Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario(new Pessoa(), new Data); 
// funcionário com Pessoa e Data
```

2) Não use acesso direto a essas propriedades, sempre use `setters` e `getters`:

```
public Pessoa getPessoa() {
  return this.pessoa;
}

public void setPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
  this.pessoa = pessoa;
}
```

Comment: @Giovane apesar do autor te aprovado a edição, você não pode fazer esse tipo de edição no site, não se deve alterar ou acrescentar conteudo na postagem, de forma a alterar o conteudo original do post, como você fez adicionando uma "tentativa de resposta". Visite [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) para ler mais a respeito do que se pode alterar nos posts do site.

Comment: @diegofm eu não adicionei nada a pergunta. Eu achei a resposta do Sorack boa e não quis adicionar uma resposta pois queria apenas complementar a resposta dele pois achei válido apresentar tal estratégia de código. Achei que seria pior eu fazer uma resposta igual a do Sorack ou uma resposta querendo completar a resposta dele.

Comment: @Giovane isso não é permitido no site, se sua resposta agrega a dele com conteudo novo, é altamente aconselhavel você responder num novo post. O link explica exatamente isso.

Comment: @Giovane vc poderia publicar uma resposta nova e citar a resposta do Sorack em sua resposta, ou fazer uma referencia, geralmente este tipo de edição não é recomendada no site, pode mudar o sentido da resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema não está no `println`! Sua classe funcionário contém alguns erros. Você não definiu um `setDatadia()`, `setDatames()`, `setDiaAno()`. Na classe principal você esqueceu de definir propriedades da `data`.

Classe principal:

```
package principal;


public class Principal {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    funcionario lucas = new funcionario();
    lucas.setSalario(1856.85);
    lucas.setEndereco("Rua Frei Caneca");
    lucas.setEstadoCivil("Solteiro");
    lucas.setNomeDoDepartamento("Auxiliar");

   lucas.pessoa = new funcionario();
    lucas.pessoa.setNome("Lucas Alves Cardoso de Jesus");
    lucas.pessoa.setRg(123456891);

    lucas.data = new funcionario();
    lucas.data.setDataDia(13);
    lucas.data.setDataMes(05);
    lucas.data.setDiaAno(94);

    lucas.getAnual();

    System.out.println(lucas.getEndereco());


}

}
```

Classe funcionario:

```
package principal;


public class funcionario {

    private String NomeDoDepartamento;
    private double Salario;
    private double anual;
    private String EstadoCivil;
    private String Endereco;
    private String nome;
    private int rg;
    int proximo = 0;
    private int dataDia;
    private int dataMes;
    private int  diaAno;

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public void setRg(int rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public void setDataDia(int dataDia) {
        this.dataDia = dataDia;
    }

    public void setDataMes(int dataMes) {
        this.dataMes = dataMes;
    }

    public void setDiaAno(int diaAno) {
        this.diaAno = diaAno;
    }
    funcionario pessoa;
    funcionario data;


    //get obter set mudar

    public String getNomeDoDepartamento(){
        return this.NomeDoDepartamento;
    }

    public void setNomeDoDepartamento(String nomedepartamento){
        this.NomeDoDepartamento = nomedepartamento;
    }

    public double getSalario(){
        return this.Salario;
    }

    public void setSalario (double salario){
        this.Salario = salario;
    }

    public double getAnual(){
        return this.Salario*12;
    }

    public String getEstadoCivil(){
        return this.EstadoCivil;
    }

    public void setEstadoCivil(String estadocivil){
        this.EstadoCivil = estadocivil;
    }

    public String getEndereco(){
        return this.Endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco (String endereco){
        this.Endereco = endereco;
    }


}
```

Comment: Unifiquei as suas duas respostas em uma só. Assim, marquei a outra para exclusão. Espero que compreenda, pois as duas respostas que você postou, na verdade se tratam de uma coisa só.